# Convert TextBox Value to integet in rowcommand event in Grid View

Tags: c#, gridview

I am trying to convert Value within the `TextBox` to int within the `RowCommand` of the `gridview`.

```
else if (e.CommandName == "UpdateRow")
{
    int rowIndex = ((GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
    int TimeSheetId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    int Sunday = Convert.ToInt32((TextBox)gvEmployeeTimeSheet.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("txtSunday"));// Error here
    int Monday = Convert.ToInt32((TextBox)gvEmployeeTimeSheet.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("txtMonday"));// Error her
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are finding the control then trying to cast it to an integer, you need to be selecting the Textbox's Text Property and converting it instead.

```
 int Sunday = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)gvEmployeeTimeSheet.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("txtSunday")).Text);
 int Monday = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)gvEmployeeTimeSheet.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("txtMonday")).Text);
```

Comment: @MarkHall: Only 1 minute difference to post answer... :)

Answer (score 1):

As the error said, you are trying to cast textbox to an integer. Which is not possible. So it should be like this -

```
int Sunday = Convert.ToInt32((TextBox)(gvEmployeeTimeSheet.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("txtSunday")).Text);
int Monday = Convert.ToInt32((TextBox)(gvEmployeeTimeSheet.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("txtMonday")).Text);
```